# Why system hangs up while using multiple tabs on firefox or chrome?

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, google-chrome

as I work with multiple tabs, no matter its firefox or chrome. Ubuntu system hangs down. I have 2 gb ram. What should I do? should I change to Lubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Because chrome consumes a lot of memory. You can use mozilla and stop the unnecessary services running at the back end.

To check the status of running services at background:

```
sudo service --status-all
```

If you want to stop a service from autostart:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f [ServiceName] remove
```

In case, if you want to stop service temporarily:

```
sudo service stop [ServiceName]
```

Hope your system will work better enough.

Comment: > 'no matter its firefox or chrome' so it also doesn't work well with Firefox

Comment: That is the reason, why I suggested to find out unnecessary services running in background and stop them. It will get the more memory to use firefox/chrome efficiently.